# PHP - Pulling array and splitting the strings

Tags: php

Not sure how to title this properly but here's the issue I am running into currently. I built a cart and checkout system and it loads all the data into a database when it finalized the order. To save some space, I stored just the item IDs originally but then I ran into the issue of if I deleted the item from the database (because it was discontinued or whatever) then it wouldn't return the info I needed. And if they ordered more then 1 item the database record would be wrong. So I stored the data like so:

`Itemid:Quantity:Price:name, itemid2:quantity2:price2:name2`
OR
`1:3:20.00:Flower Hat, 2:1:17.75:diamonds`

The issue I have right now that I need help with is this. I need to seperate the four values into variables like `$price`, `$item`, `$id`, `$ammount` so I can display them on the order history page and I need to loop through all items on the array so I can print a row for each item with all four fields respective to that item.

I use strpos already to get the shipping info from the same database field which is formatted as METHOD:Price but since I have 3 :'s on my string I'm not sure how to go through each one. Thanks.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a function

```
function parseItems($dbjunk){
    $cart = array();
    $items = explode(",",$dbjunk);
    foreach($items as $i){
        $chunks = explode(":", $i);
        $cart[] = array(
            "ItemID" => $chunks[0] ,
            "Quantity" => $chunks[1] ,
            "Price" => $chunks[2] ,
            "name" => $chunks[3]
        );
    }
    return $cart;
}
```

Example usage:

```
$dbjunk = "Itemid:Quantity:Price:name, itemid2:quantity2:price2:name2";
$parsed = parseItems($dbjunk);
print_r($parsed);
```

See: https://3v4l.org/rBkXF

If you need variables instead of an array you can use `list()`, like this..

```
$dbjunk = "Itemid:Quantity:Price:name, itemid2:quantity2:price2:name2";
$parsed = parseItems($dbjunk);
foreach($parsed as $p){
    list($itemID, $Quantity, $Price, $name) = array_values($p);
    var_dump($itemID, $Quantity, $Price, $name);
}
```

see: https://3v4l.org/l4vsn

Comment: I used this function and it solved my problem right away. Thanks for the responses guys.

Answer (score 0):

Read about [First Normal Form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form). Basically, you want to store one value in one field. So, instead of this:

```
shipping = "method:price"
```

You want something like this:

```
shipping_method = "method"
shipping_price = "price"
```

Don't concern yourself with space -- it's essentially free nowadays.

Regarding your deleted items dilemma, your initial implementation was the way to go:

```
I stored just the item IDs originally
```

In addition to reverting to this technique, I would recommend two things:

- Add a boolean field to your item table to represent if the item is currently available or not. This gives you the additional feature of being able to toggle items on/off without having to delete/insert records and change ids.
- Before deleting an item, check to see if it's ever been ordered. If not, it's ok to delete. If so, instead just deactivate it.

Answer (score 0):

You should not physically delete items from your database. Instead, put a new column named 'is_active' or something like that to indicate whether the product is active/non-deleted.
Answering your question, here is my suggestion:

```
$orderString = '1:3:20.00:Flower Hat, 2:1:17.75:diamonds';
$items = array();
foreach(explode(', ', $orderString) as $itemString) {
    $itemData = explode(':', $itemString);
    $items[] = array(
        'id' => $itemData[0],
        'amount' => $itemData[1],
        'value' => $itemData[2],
        'description' => $itemData[3]
    );
}
```

with this code, you will obtain an array with the data of all the items in the string, no matter how much items are in the string

Answer (score 0):

try something like

```
$data = 1:3:20.00:Flower Hat, 2:1:17.75:diamonds
list($price, $item, $uid, $id, $ammount) = explode(":", $data);
echo $user; 
 echo $item;
```